# Display Username Blank in App Timeout

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting blank User even though i am setting the value in NSUSERdefault.Its working with Lock mode but same code is not working for timeout of App (5 min) User is  vcLogin.usernameTxt?.text =  uname is coming blank even NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username") as! String has value

```
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vcLogin = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! LoginViewController
            var uname:String!
            if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username") != nil) {
                print("username =\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username"))")
               uname = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username") as! String
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            }else{
              uname = ""
            }



            let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

            var arr=[UIViewController]()
            arr = (navVC?.viewControllers)!


            if ((arr.last?.isKindOfClass(LoginViewController)) != nil) {

               arr.append(vcLogin)
                navVC?.viewControllers = arr
                print("name=\(uname)")
                //if uname != nil {
                vcLogin.usernameTxt?.text =  uname
                //}
            }






        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let theUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")!
print("username =\(theUsername)")
```

By the way, why do you use Swift 2?

Comment: Yes , Swift 2.3

Comment: vcLogin.usernameTxt?.text  is coming Nil even though Uname has value ,in timeout mode after 5 min app shows login page